# jQuery click doesn't work in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

jQuery click doesn't work in `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/XXXXXXX`

Here is the div that I'm trying to click.

```
<div class="j-Ta-pb j-ia-e a-Cs-A-e a-d-e" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-tooltip="More actions" aria-label="More actions" tabindex="0"><div class="a-e-d"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 20 20" height="20px" width="20px" y="0px" x="0px"><path d="M10,6c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2S8,2.895,8,4S8.896,6,10,6z M10,8c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2  S11.104,8,10,8z M10,14c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2S11.104,14,10,14z" fill="#000000"/></svg></div></div>
```

In Firebug console I run command `$('.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e').click();`

And I'm getting this :

```
Object[div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e, div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e, div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e, div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e]
```

I also tried to change :eq from :eq(0) to ;eq(4) - nothing changes, It doesn't show "More actions" options.

+++UPDATE+++

jQuery does work

```
var script = window.content.document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: That behaviour is correct. The `click()` method returns a jQuery object containing the clicked element which is what you see in the console. If triggering that click event has no effect then it could be for a separate reason, such as the event is not bound at the point you click, or the event handler is not bound to that element.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive doesn't seem to have jQuery on it. There are many ways you can tell it's not jQuery, one of the easiest is $.fn is undefined.

It turns out that web developer consoles (at least in recent versions of Firefox and Chrome) alias $ to a query selector that is similar to jQuery's, though not identical. This is likely what you're seeing here. Check out the documentation for Firefox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Helper_commands).

If you need jQuery in the page this should get you started.

Good luck!

Comment: If jQuery wasn't included on the page OP would have received an error saying `$ is undefined`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not true, take a look at the link posted in my answer.  OP was executing this through the developer console.  Some developer consoles inject their own $ as a helper method for debugging (unless $ is defined on window)

Answer (score 0):

.click() has been deprecated for a while try using

```
$('.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e').on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // Do something here
});
```

Comment: Thank you.
Getting the same 
Object[div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e, div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e, div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e, div.j-Ta-pb.j-ia-e.a-Cs-A-e.a-d-e]
It doesn't show "More actions" options.

Comment: @OddDev I was confused with .live() :)